# How to initialize immutable class members in external (ini) function

Tags: kotlin, java-native-interface

Is it possible to create a Kotlin class like this:

```
class Test {
    val x:String
    val y:String

    external fun initFromData(data:ByteArray)
    constructor(data:ByteArray) {
        initFromData(data)
    }
}
```

Without getting an error on "Property must be initialized or be abstract"?  Is there a way to tell Kotlin that initFromData is initializing x and y?  Or, another way to go about this?

Comment: Have `initFromData()` return a `Pair` (or other object) holding the two values, and assign them to `x` and `y` in the constructor?

Comment: @gidds thanks, yes, I guess that would work.  But, that makes me think I might as well return a Test object directly from a companion member function.  I have another constructor that initializes all the fields (not shown); the error only arises when I add this second constructor that does not.